# Trouble returning json in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to replace the 'return' from the sankey code below with a variable, but it's not returning as expected.

```
return {
"nodes": [{"node": 0,"name": "node 1",color: "#008000"},
{"node": 1,"name": "node 2",color: "#99cc00"},
{"node": 2,"name": "node 3",color: "#00ff00"}],
"links": [{"source": 0,"target": 2,"value": 2},
{"source": 1,"target": 2,"value": 4}]
};
```

So now, I would like to use this method instead, as I am intending to do some manipulation first before returning.

```
var calloutx = '"nodes" : [';
calloutx += '{"node" : 0,"name" : "node 1","color : #008000"},';
calloutx += '{"node" : 1,"name" : "node 2","color : #99cc00"},';
calloutx += '{"node" : 2,"name" : "node 3","color : #00ff00"}';
calloutx += '],"links" : [';
calloutx += '{"source" : 0,"target" : 2,"value" : 2},';
calloutx += '{"source" : 1,"target" : 2,"value" : 4}';
calloutx += ']';
return calloutx;
```

Which is doesn't return anything. I have tried json.stringify as well.

**Edit**

Apology, let me be more clear. Currently, I'm using the following script: http://bl.ocks.org/FabricioRHS/80ef58d4390b06305c91fdc831844009

So if you see at the bottom, there is this code below.

```
function getData() {
        return {
            "nodes": [{xxx1}, {xxx2}, {xxx3}],
            "links": [{xxx4}, {xxx5}, {xxx6}]
            };
    };
```

In simple sense, I know i that I can just do a

```
json.stringify("nodes": [{xxx1}, {xxx2}, {xxx3}],
            "links": [{xxx4}, {xxx5}, {xxx6}]).
```

But before this, I'm running some codes to generate the 2 arrays.

```
var nodex = [{xxx1},{xxx2},{xxx3}]
var linkx = [{xxx4},{xxx5},{xxx6}]
```

Then I want to combine and stringify both array together. Specifically I want to add the individual items from nodex and linkx to the "nodes" and "links" collections of the returned data.

***Additional Edit***

The pseudo script is as below. I'm making it as simple as possible.

```
var nodex = [];
nodex.push({"node": 0,"name": "node 1",color: "#008000"});
nodex.push({"node": 1,"name": "node 2",color: "#99cc00"});

var linkx = [];
linkx.push({"source" : 0,"target" : 1,"value" : 2});

//How nodex and linkx are generated is not relevant in this context.

return { '"nodes" : [' + json.stringify(nodex) + '], "links": [' + json.stringify(linkx) + ']' };

//I want the above to achieve the exact same result if I were to do the below

return {"nodes": [{"node": 0,"name": "node 1",color: "#008000"},{"node":1,"name": "node 2",color: "#99cc00"},],"links": [{"source": 0,"target": 2,"value": 2}]};
```

Comment: `return` to what? How is the function that it returns to used? There simply isn't enough shown for anyone here to troubleshoot. Take a few minutes to thoroughly read [ask] and [mcve] then edit the question with enough details for others to assess the full issue

Comment: The author is confused about strings vs objects, but the question makes sense.

Comment: you mean you want to combine the object return from getData() with the two arrays you're generating? I assume you want to add the individual items from nodex and linkx to the "nodes" and "links" collections of the returned data, is that correct? It might clarify things 100% if you showed an example of the desired final output (ideally with a small amount of real data, not xxx1 xxx2)

Comment: "I assume you want to add the individual items from nodex and linkx to the "nodes" and "links" collections of the returned data, is that correct?" -> Yes, this is correct. The output is a sankey diagram: http://bl.ocks.org/FabricioRHS/80ef58d4390b06305c91fdc831844009

Comment: "The output is a sankey diagram". Yes, but for the purpose of this, please take one step back and consider the output to be a modified object. You're asking how to modify the object, so stick to that. The diagram is, for now, irrelevant. That happens later, after you've changed the object. So just show us exactly how you want the altered object to look.

Comment: Anyway I think I figured out what you need - see new answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will combine the object returned by getData() with the data from the arrays you've generated yourself, adding the items to the nodes and links collections of the getData result.

You can then stringify it afterwards. Demo:

```js
function getData() {
  return {
    "nodes": [{
        "node": 0,
        "name": "node 1",
        color: "#008000"
      },
      {
        "node": 1,
        "name": "node 2",
        color: "#99cc00"
      },
      {
        "node": 2,
        "name": "node 3",
        color: "#00ff00"
      }
    ],
    "links": [{
        "source": 0,
        "target": 2,
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 2,
        "value": 4
      }
    ]
  };
}

var nodex = [{
    "node": 90,
    "name": "node 90",
    "color": "#00ff00"
  },
  {
    "node": 91,
    "name": "node 91",
    "color": "green"
  },
  {
    "node": 92,
    "name": "node 92",
    "color": "#cccccc"
  }
];
var linkx = [{
    "source": 200,
    "target": 300,
    "value": 400
  },
  {
    "source": 500,
    "target": 600,
    "value": 700
  }, {
    "source": 800,
    "target": 900,
    "value": 1000
  }
];

var result = getData();

nodex.forEach(function(el) {
  result.nodes.push(el);
});
linkx.forEach(function(el) {
  result.links.push(el);
});

var str = JSON.stringify(result);
console.log(str);
```

N.B. `nodex[]` and `linkx[]` (from your example code) isn't valid syntax...I've made an assumption about what you mean by that.

Comment: I think the getdata() is causing confusion. I have omitted it in the additional edit, so that we can focus on the json.stringify portion.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't really make any sense. Stringifying is the last, trivial, one-line part, done automatically. You should never try to do it by hand - you just make it very likely that you'll introduce errors. Use code to create the object you want, with the structure you want, and then, when it's ready, you stringify it.

Comment: Maybe you just need to be doing `return JSON.stringify({ "nodes": nodex, "links": linkx });` or something. But TBH it's unclear whether you actually need JSON here at all. Unless you are transmitting the data via HTTP or storing it somewhere, it's not a very useful format. If you're trying to pass this to D3, I don't know this library but I would guess it would prefer to receive an actual usable code object, rather than a JSON string (since it would just have to parse the JSON again in order to make use of it). So maybe actually `return { "nodes": nodex, "links": linkx };` is all you need.

Comment: holly, your last statement works, I was thinking too complex.

Answer (score 1):

A clean way to use a **variable** to `return` the value as a JSON string is to:

1. Define the data as a JavaScript object literal
2. Use the `JSON.stringify()` function to convert the object to a string
3. `return` the result

Code:

```
const data = {
   nodes: [
      { node: 0, name: 'node 1', color: '#008000' },
      { node: 1, name: 'node 2', color: '#99cc00' },
      { node: 2, name: 'node 3', color: '#00ff00' }
   ],
   links: [
      { source: 0, target: 2, value: 2 },
      { source: 1, target: 2, value: 4 }
   ]
};
return JSON.stringify(data);
```

Fiddle with the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/puj70v3o/

[image]